# Can I get (something like) an Apple wireless keyboard with numeric keypad?

Tags: keyboard, hardware-recommendation

That would be perfect; their current wireless keyboard is too laptop-like. I like having wide arrow keys, the delete/end/page up/page down/home keys.

Otherwise, can someone recommend a similar option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agree with Loïc that this question should be rephrased, but if you're looking for a possible solution without being subject to Apple's whims, there are many third-party bluetooth keypads available...

- [LMP Bluetooth Keypad](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004CB56XE) -- meant to attach to an Apple wireless keyboard, but has mixed reviews
- [Microsoft Bluetooth Keypad](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002NP13C4) -- blasphemy, I know, but it has good reviews
- [Logitech Wireless Keypad](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0034XRDU0) -- non-Bluetooth alternative that uses Logitech's mini USB receiver

Comment: It should not be overlooked that the MS and Logitech options have a different layout than the standard Mac keypad; the plus key is oversized, there's no equals key, and the slash, star and minus keys are in different positions, as per the standard PC keyboard layout. It took me quite a bit of time to adjust to those differences after I started purchasing ergo keyboards (which unfortunately almost never come in Mac-specific versions) to use with my Macs.

Comment: @Garrett You raise a good point.  Many (most?) people use keypads by touch, so even small variations in what someone is used to could lead to problems.

Answer (score 3):

Apple made a "normal" style wireless keyboard a few years ago. They are still available second hand.  Search for "apple wireless keyboard A1016"

Answer (score 1):

Speculating on when Apple will release something is pointless, but here's a nice-looking alternative:

[http://www.amazon.com/dp/B004CB56XE](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004CB56XE)

Answer (score 0):

I have [this one](http://www.rocketfishproducts.com/products/computers/RF-ABTKB.html). It has the command key instead of the windows key you'll find most of the time.

It's been discontinued but I still see it regularly at the local Futureshop and Best Buy here in Sherbrooke, QC Canada.