# full wireless keyboard for iMac

Tags: keyboard, imac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [full wireless keyboard for iMac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17645/full-wireless-keyboard-for-imac)

Are you aware of any full (with numpad, apple keys, preferably german layout) wireless keyboard that works well with the (latest gen) iMac and resembles the iMac design.

I am not asking for shopping suggestions. I would just like know if such products exists. So I suppose I am within the rules of this forum.

The suggestions of numpad adapters made here: [Can I get (something like) an Apple wireless keyboard with numeric keypad?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/13108/3293) do not qualify as an answer, because I try to find products that are actual keyboards.

Comment: Do you care if it's not manufactured by Apple?

Comment: It doesn't have to be apple and it doesn't have to look **exactly** like the apple keyboards.

Comment: Then you can buy any wireless keyboard. If you buy one designed for PCs, it will work, but the Windows key will be the Command (Apple) key in OS X.

Answer (score -2):

Still a little bit ugly but his one comes pretty close:

[Swann kw10 Wireless Keyboard](http://www.swannsecurity.com/s/products/view/?product=1012)

[image]
<sub>(source: [swannsecurity.com](http://www.swannsecurity.com/images/hires/wkb.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Erm, this isn't Quertzu.